# Does migration to FCM HTTP v1 need changes in app side?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Does migration to FCM HTTP v1 only affect serverside?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

There is no word of changes needed into app.

e.g;

- google-services.json
- firebase-messaging deps version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is no word of changes needed into app.

That's because there are no changes required.

If you read the linked documentation thoroughly, and its linked materials, you'll find that the changes are entirely in the protocol with the FCM API for sending messages from your backend.